# Pig Script output

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to pig script and encountered the following pig script.I understood the first two lines but i am not getting clarity from "C=group B by.." can some one please explain me the code?

```
A = LOAD ’page views’ AS (user, action, timespent, query term, ip addr, 
timestamp,estimated revenue, page info, page links);
B = FOREACH A generate user, estimated revenue;
C = GROUP B by user parallel 40;
D = FOREACH C
     E = ORDER B by estimated revenue;
     F = E.estimated revenue;
     GENERATE group, SUM(F);
ENDFOR
STORE D into ’L16out’;
```

Thanks in advance.